# java sockets programming

Tags: java

i have been trying to write some programs on java sockets and i got stuck with this problem. 
Normally the INetAddress object is created using the factory methods getLocalHost(), getbyAddress(byte[]) and getbyName(string).... when I use getbyName function...

for example...

```
INetAddress a=InetAddress.getbyName("www.google.com");
```

and trying to print the above object using println method i was getting Unknown host exception but actually i heard that it would perform a DNS query and return one of the IP address of a server  of google.com but its not working that way... i used netbeans to run the program and our college has a proxy server also.

One more thing... if i use the getbyName(string) and give an argument as some others PC name who is within the college network then can it resolve the system IP address ? . In my case this was unable to resolve..
  I checked by turning the windows firewall to off state also but in vain....
please help...

`ping www.google.com` is showing *"ping request could not find the host name google.com"*

Comment: Socket can just take a host as a port in the constructor. so, you can just do Socket s = new Socket("www.google.com", 80); this will probably result in the same problem - if your dns is not configured properly.

Comment: What do you get if you do a ping ``www.google.com``

Comment: its showing "ping request could not find the host name google.com"

Comment: How to configure the DNS..?? im using windows 7 premium... and also will it resolve the system names in the same network...
for example...
getbyName("example-PC");
will it give the IP address of the system??

Comment: There is your answer, it's a networking issue, nothing to do with your code.

Comment: please let me know how to overcome it.....

Comment: Sorry, never used windows 7 plus I have no idea what your network looks like.  Try asking your sysadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name resolution strategy used by `InetAddress.getByName` depends on the operating system. If the OS is configured to use DNS to resolve names, that's what `InetAddress.getByName` will use. (Probably.)

To check that DNS is working correctly you can run `nslookup www.google.com` from a terminal.

> One more thing... if i use the getbyName(string) and give an argument as some others PC name who is within the college network then can it resolve the system IP address ?

If other programs on your system can resolve the name to an IP address so should Java.

Comment: You say that `ping` cannot find the host name. That should tell you it's not using DNS, or that your DNS servers don't know about `google.com`. Either way it looks like you need to use a proxy if you want to connect to the internet.

Comment: actually our college uses proxy server... so is that the problem for this... if i connect directly through a packet data connection will i get a change in the result??

Comment: Of course. When you connect through a proxy your machine doesn't resolve the host name. It just tells the proxy "please connect to this machine and make this request for me".